# classification with keras: input data shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

I am trying to modify the classification example show in the keras' [blog](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p250qtchothxd7c/data_short.zip?dl=0) to classify a images in 3 different classes.

I have 3000 images (3 x 1000) of training and 1200 (3 x 400) of validation.
The code is modified to classify 3 clases.

The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import applications

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

top_model_weights_path = 'bottleneck_fc_model.h5'
train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
nb_train_samples = 3000
nb_validation_samples = 1200
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

n_classes = 3


def save_bottlebeck_features():
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

    # build the VGG16 network
    model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False)
    bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
        generator, nb_train_samples // batch_size)
    np.save(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'wb'),
            bottleneck_features_train)

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False)
    bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(
        generator, nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
    np.save(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy', 'wb'),
            bottleneck_features_validation)


def train_top_model():
    train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy','rb'))
    train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes) + [1] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes) + \
                            [2] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes))

    validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy','rb'))
    validation_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes) + [1] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes) + \
                                 [2] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes))

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, \
              validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
    model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)
```

When I finally execute the two functions:

```
save_bottlebeck_features()
train_top_model()
```

The second function returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-070a6188c611> in <module>()
      4 print(validation_labels.shape)
      5 
----> 6 train_top_model()

<ipython-input-129-ea2b02024693> in train_top_model()
     64                   loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
     65 
---> 66     model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,               validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
     67     model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    865                               class_weight=class_weight,
    866                               sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 867                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
    868 
    869     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1520             class_weight=class_weight,
   1521             check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1522             batch_size=batch_size)
   1523         # Prepare validation data.
   1524         do_validation = False

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_batch_axis, batch_size)
   1380                                     output_shapes,
   1381                                     check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1382                                     exception_prefix='target')
   1383         sample_weights = _standardize_sample_weights(sample_weight,
   1384                                                      self._feed_output_names)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    142                             ' to have shape ' + str(shapes[i]) +
    143                             ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 144                             str(array.shape))
    145     return arrays
    146 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_58 to have shape (None, 3) but got array with shape (3000, 1)
```

If I print the shape of the data and labels, it returns:

```
print(train_labels.shape)
(3000, 3)
print(train_data.shape)
(3000, 3)
print(validation_data.shape)
(1200, 4, 4, 512)
print(validation_labels.shape)
(1200,)
```

**EDIT**:

I'm posting the full code as well as the database with the images that I'm considering.

The database can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p250qtchothxd7c/data_short.zip?dl=0).

The code is the following:

```
# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

top_model_weights_path = 'what.h5'#'bottleneck_fc_model.h5'
train_data_dir = 'data_short/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data_short/validation'
nb_train_samples = 30
nb_validation_samples = 6
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

n_classes = 3


def save_bottlebeck_features():
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

    # build the VGG16 network
    model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height),\
                                            batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)

    bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(generator, nb_train_samples // batch_size)

    np.save(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'wb'), bottleneck_features_train)

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height),\
                                            batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)

    bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(generator, nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

    np.save(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy', 'wb'), bottleneck_features_validation)


def train_top_model():
    encoder = OneHotEncoder()
    #train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy','rb'))
    train_data = np.load('bottleneck_features_train.npy')

    train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes) + [1] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes) + 
                            [2] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes))

    train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)


    validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy','rb'))
    validation_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_validation_samples // n_classes) + \
                                 [1] * (nb_validation_samples // n_classes) + \
                                 [2] * (nb_validation_samples // n_classes))

    validation_labels = to_categorical(validation_labels)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,\
              validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
    model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)
```

The error given is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-6869607a6e44> in <module>()
----> 1 train_top_model()

<ipython-input-6-933b6592c6c1> in train_top_model()
     56     model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
     57 
---> 58     model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,              validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
     59     model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    861                               class_weight=class_weight,
    862                               sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 863                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
    864 
    865     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
   1356             class_weight=class_weight,
   1357             check_batch_axis=False,
-> 1358             batch_size=batch_size)
   1359         # Prepare validation data.
   1360         if validation_data:

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_batch_axis, batch_size)
   1244                           for (ref, sw, cw, mode)
   1245                           in zip(y, sample_weights, class_weights, self._feed_sample_weight_modes)]
-> 1246         _check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
   1247         _check_loss_and_target_compatibility(y,
   1248                                              self._feed_loss_fns,

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _check_array_lengths(inputs, targets, weights)
    235                          'the same number of samples as target arrays. '
    236                          'Found ' + str(list(set_x)[0]) + ' input samples '
--> 237                          'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
    238     if len(set_w) > 1:
    239         raise ValueError('All sample_weight arrays should have '

ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 16 input samples and 30 target samples.
```

**EDIT2** The solution:

I solve this problem making a fundamental change in the code. It can be seen [here](http://www.codesofinterest.com/2017/08/bottleneck-features-multi-class-classification-keras.html?m=1).

Comment: `train_lables.shape[1]` should be `=` to `validation_labels.shape[1]` and `train_data.shape[1],train_data.shape[2],train_data.shape[3]` should be equal to `validation_data.shape[1],validation_data.shape[2],validation_data.shape[3]`, and this should be clear, because the only difference between data test and data validate is the first diminsion, which is the total number of "samples" you have

Comment: I think that this is not the problem. I reduce the system for 10 images each class for the training and 2 images for validation. The tensor sizes are correct, it obeys to the rule that you presented. However I still have the error.

Comment: ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 16 input samples and 30 target samples.

Comment: Can you update the code to reflect this, it just seems now that your `train_data.shape[0]` is not equal to `train_labels.shape[0]`

Comment: You're still giving as labels an array with only 1 class. The error message now says your labels are shaped like `(30,1)`. There's something wrong in the way you create your labels.

Comment: I made another change. I'm stuck in this problem for 3 days already.

Comment: Why do you use `encoder.fit_transform` in your labels? Where are your labels coming from? And what is the encoder? --- It's clear that the problem is in how you are creating the labels. Don't you have a list of classes for your images?

Comment: Yes, I do. The training images are 10 birds, 10 cats and 10 dogs. I use the encoder in order to try your suggestion above, to convert a (30,1) matrix to a (30,3).

Comment: Please see the update in my answer.

Comment: please see the update of the inicial post. I just update the code in EDIT and the error.

Comment: You have 16 images, you can't have 30 results, you must have 16 results.

Comment: No, I have 30 images. Is somehow related with the batch size, because if I put batch_size=1 it works. The labels should change with the batch_size.

Comment: I could not find the error. However a clean implementation is here: http://www.codesofinterest.com/2017/08/bottleneck-features-multi-class-classification-keras.html?m=1

Comment: Since in the initial problem, you trackback showed a problem with the output dim, and @Daniel correctly answered this problem you should mark his answer as correct. There are too many question on the [tag:keras] tag that dont have marked answers and should...

Answer (score 2):

- You have "input data", which is your set of images. - Shape: `(BatchSize,w,h,channels)`
- And you have "output data / true values / predictions" which are the classes. Shape: `(BatchSize,3)`

The error message tells you that you're giving the model output data shaped like `(BatchSize,1)`, which will not fit the model.

So, you certainly got a problem when creating `train_labels`.

You must make it be shaped as `(3000,3)`. And the indices related to each class should be 1:

- Class 1: [1,0,0]
- Class 2: [0,1,0]
- Class 3: [0,0,1]

You may have combined classes (if that's possible in your case).

---

**Use keras.utils.to_categorical()**

But make sure that `train_labels.shape[0]` is exactly the same as `train_data.shape[0]`.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes) + [1] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes) + 
                        [2] * (nb_train_samples // n_classes))

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
```

---

**Another very simple way of creating the labels:**

```
train_labels = np.zeros((30,3))
train_labels[:10,0] = 1.
train_labels[10:20,1] = 1.
train_labels[20:,2] = 1.
```

Comment: But when I print the shape of the tensor it says that it is a 3000,3. print(train_labels.shape) (3000, 3)

Comment: Well, do that print immediately before calling `fit` (print from **inside** the `train_top_model()` function). The model is receiving `(3000,1)`.

Comment: @Daniel, I think initially this was the problem, and should be the accepted answer, but now OP is having a problem with the shape of the input data, which shows 16 samples

Comment: Also believe it has to do with the `steps=` argument in the `predict_generator()` in his `save_bottlebeck_features` function or in combination with the `batch_size` argument in the flow from directory. Dont know enough about `VGG16` and cant run his code, but I think thats the new problem